# What are the activity types for the Copy to Slack, Copy to Contacts and Skype options for exclusion from the ActionSheetIOS API?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

I'm trying to give the user the option of sharing details of a contact as a `VCF` file via `ActionSheetIOS`, but I have only found the

```
com.apple.UIKit.activity.AddToReadingList, com.apple.UIKit.activity.CopyToPasteboard,
com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension
com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension
```

activity type strings so far.  The file is being accessed using the Contacts.writeContactToFileAsync API. Where would I be able to find the the others mentioned in the question?

I have tried this link: [uiactivitytype](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivitytype), searching `Reddit`'s React Native and iOSProgramming subreddits, `GitHub`, `Stack Overflow`, `Google` and `DuckDuckGo`(sometimes Google presents unrelated results) using '`UIActivityType`' and '`excludedActivityTypes`' as search terms along with the target option(e.g. Copy to Slack).  I found this string, '`com.tinyspeck.chatlyio.share`' on Stack Overflow, but it doesn't do anything and I figure it would also remove the Slack share option.  I also tried the string, '`com.skype.skype.sharingextension`' to remove the Skype one, but that doesn't work either.

```
_onShareOptions = async () => {
    const {id} = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    console.log('id', id);
    const contactUri = await Contacts.writeContactToFileAsync({ id: id });
    console.log('contactUri', contactUri);
    ActionSheetIOS.showShareActionSheetWithOptions({
      url: contactUri,
      excludedActivityTypes: [
        'com.apple.UIKit.activity.AddToReadingList',
        'com.apple.UIKit.activity.CopyToPasteboard',
        'com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension',
        'com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension',
      ]
    }, () => {}, () => {});
  }
```

I expect to be able to remove the 'Copy to Slack', 'Copy to Contacts', and 'Skype' share options from the Action Sheet.